# Limit for number of files AND size to upload in salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, attachment, governorlimits

On my page I have an `<input="file" />` and I allow the users to select as many files as they want before they insert them in salesforce.

When the user triggers the uploading process I pass each file separately to the back end and upload it in salesforce.

This is all working fine and I have no issues. However:

1. I wonder if there is a limit for the number of files that could be
   uploaded for an object in salesforce?
2. Is there a limit to the combined file size for all attachments for
   an object?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to both questions are: no. There's no limit to the number of attachments a record may have, nor is there a limit to the file size on a record. Of course, you should note that there *is* a limit on the total number of file bytes you can store (see Storage Usage in Setup), so you could kind of consider that the maximum number of bytes you can store on a record... except that there's a little grace period beyond what's stated in Setup, so even that isn't technically accurate.